# Why do I have a mysterious reputation change on my profile?

Tags: support, reputation

I had $256$ reputation on MSE till yesterday. But today when I checked my account, it had decreased down to $216$. I did not post any question or answer in the past few days and there is no new upvote/downvote on any of my posts. The reputation change is also not visible in the reputation tab in my profile and the last reputation change was on July 20 as shown on the webpage. The reputation curve also modified cleverly and it does not show that I had 256 reputation ever even though I had.

[image]

Now you might be thinking that I never gained 256 reputation, but I did have it and I also had View close votes privilege. The Achievements tab mentions that I received View close votes privilege.

[image]

But now I no longer have that privilege due to this unknown loss of reputation.

Can someone please tell why my reputation changed mysteriously overnight even after no new post?

Comment: At the end of the page of your reputation https://math.stackexchange.com/users/935059/riverx15?tab=reputation there would be a option Show deleted posts like https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Kl0.png . Is that option checked? If not please check it and tell are you able to see the rep change

Comment: For a better view where is the option see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoBiw.png

Comment: @JitendraSingh Yes. One of the answers with exactly that amount of reputation that I lost has been deleted because the original post has been deleted. Thank you very much.

Comment: good to know that helps you. Let me write this as answer

Comment: Nothing mysterious about it,  you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have not selected "Show deleted posts" options at the end of [the reputation page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation). Select that and you will see why there was a drop of reputation.

Comment: Hello :) I have almost the same problem. Do I lose reputation on my answer, even if the whole question was deleted? I haven't expected that.

Comment: @Jochen yes if the question is deleted then all the answer associated with it will be delete and the reputation will be decreased as a answer without a question is quite meaningless but for me it is funny :)

Comment: @Jochen  If a question is deleted by community members, then typically, the question should never have been answered, and as a consequence, the post and the answers, are deleted.  We encourage users to answer only questions that meet site standards.

Comment: Thank you, then i delete one of my posts

Comment: @Jochen, there's a sort of statute of limitations operating there. I think the way it works is that if your answer is 60 days older or more, then you don't lose any points if the question is deleted.

Comment: @GerryMyerson FYI, you're partially correct. As stated & discussed in the Meta [Conditions for keeping reputation in case of post deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327540/562482) question & answer, the post needs to also have a score $\ge 3$.

Comment: Thank you :) I've just deleted one of my posts.